# How can I be sure a constructor function only runs once?

Tags: rxjs, observable, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way for this code in the constructor of my service TranslatorService is calling just one time for all application or on demande, and not all time homecomponent is load ????

```
this.translations$ = translationsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        ...
      })
```

translation class for my translate retrive from firestore ex:

```
{
  "WELCOME": {
   "FR": "bienvenue",
   "GB": "Welcome"
 }
}

export interface Translation {
    [code: string]: TranslationInfo;

}

export interface TranslationInfo {
    [language: string]: string;
}
```

my core module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { TranslatorService } from '../services/translator.service';
@NgModule({
imports: [
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule
],
providers: [AuthService, TranslatorService]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

injected in appmodule

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
...

],
imports: [
...
    CoreModule,
...
],
providers: [AuthGuard],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my translator service

```
    @Injectable()
export class TranslatorService {

  translationsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Translation>;
  translations$: Observable<any>;
  public translations: Translation[];

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    var translationsCollection = this.afs.collection("translations");
    this.translations$ = translationsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        ...
      })
    });
```

my component

```
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
translations$: Observable<any>;
constructor(private translator: TranslatorService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.translations$ = this.translator.translations$;
}
```

my component view

```
<div *ngFor="let translation of translations$|async">
<pre>{{translation | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar in one of my projects. You just need to move your translation code one level above. i.e.

Make a component called translation component which wraps all the components and put your logic in it. That way it will be loaded only once through the application life cycle.

You route config should then look something as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: LanguageComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        ]
    }
];
```

Basically all your application is wrapped into Language component.

Comment: It seem a good idea, i try it this day or tommorow, i come back to tell you if all it's good, thank you

Comment: i finally change my road map and choose ngx-translate to manage multi language

Comment: I am using the same but I still use the language component for language specific actions. Particularly doing RTL.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a singleton pattern: move the code to a static function and store its result in a static field.  The constructor just calls the static function which will check the field before running its code:

```
export class TranslatorService {

  translationsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Translation>;
  translations$: Observable<any>;

  static tCollection : AngularFirestoreCollection<Translation>;
  static t$: Observable<any>;
  static initialize(afs: AngularFireStore) : void {
    if (TranslatorService.tCollection == null) {
      TranslatorService.tCollection = afs.collection("translations");
      TranslatorService.t$ = TranslatorService.tCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => actions.map(a => ...));
    }
  }

  public translations: Translation[];

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    TranslatorService.initialize(this.afs);
    this.translations$ = TranslatorService.t$;
    this.translationsCollection = TranslatorService.tCollection;
  }
}
```

Comment: in angular service are singleton, this is not a good answer, the probleme come from this line in constructor service

      `TranslatorService.t$ = 
      TranslatorService.tCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => 
      actions.map(a => ...));`
and in my component


    `ngOnInit() {
    this.translations$ = this.translator.translations$;
}`
my component view
<div *ngFor="let translation of translations$|async">
<pre>{{translation | json}}</pre>
</div>